# assign_vertex_id：problems when creating the node ids

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

Before using pgrouting, I have to create the node ids.
I loaded my polyline layer into PostGIS Manager：

[image]
[image]
[image]

I type this in SQL query：

```
select assign_vertex_id('split_4', 800, 'geom', 'gid')
```

But as I click the "Execute" button, I got this error：
[image]

```
Error: Function StartPoint (geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT gid AS id, StartPoint (geom) AS source, EndPoint (geom) ...
                          ^
HINT: did not comply with the specified name and parameter types of function. You may need to add explicit type conversion.
QUERY: SELECT gid AS id, StartPoint (geom) AS source, EndPoint (geom) as target FROM split_4
CONTEXT: PL / pgSQL function "assign_vertex_id" line 23 at target EXECUTE statement FOR
```

I searched for ST_StartPoint, and found that it needs working with linestring, so I cut my multilinestring to a linestring(named it "ways"), and then run the SQL：

```
ALTER TABLE ways ADD COLUMN source integer;
ALTER TABLE ways ADD COLUMN target integer;
SELECT assign_vertex_id('ways', 800, 'the_geom', 'gid');
```

but got the same error above.

How to solve this and to create the node ids, then I can proceed to the next step in [A Beginner’s Guide to pgRouting](http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/)？I'm working with **pgadmin3, postgresql8.4, PostGIS2.0 under WIN7-64bits**.

Comment: Possible options: postgis not loaded, pgrouting wants a different version of postgis? Does it work (or complain about EndPoint instead) if you change it to say ST_StartPoint? If it does, that would suggest version mismatch. If it doesn't that would suggest missing postgis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change to work with PostGIS 1.5, and it works!